# How to get all permutations of string as list of strings (instead of list of tuples)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, tuples, python-itertools

The goal was to create a list of all possible combinations of certain letters in a word... Which is fine, except it now ends up as a list of tuples with too many quotes and commas.

```
import itertools

mainword = input(str("Enter a word: "))
n_word = int((len(mainword)))

outp = (list(itertools.permutations(mainword,n_word)))
```

What I want:

```
[yes, yse, eys, esy, sye, sey]
```

What I'm getting:

```
[('y', 'e', 's'), ('y', 's', 'e'), ('e', 'y', 's'), ('e', 's', 'y'), ('s', 'y', 'e'), ('s', 'e', 'y')]
```

Looks to me I just need to remove all the brackets, quotes, and commas.

I've tried:

```
def remove(old_list, val):
  new_list = []
  for items in old_list:
    if items!=val:
        new_list.append(items)
  return new_list
  print(new_list)
```

where I just run the function a few times. But it doesn't work.

Comment: A side note: do not use `str("...")`, "Enter a word: " is already a string. Same about `int(len...))`. `len` already returns an int.

Comment: "Looks to me I just need to remove all the brackets, quotes, and commas." no. You need to convert a list of tuples to a list of strings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the join function . Below code works perfect .
I am also attach the screenshot of the output.

```
import itertools

mainword = input(str("Enter a word: "))
n_word = int((len(mainword)))

outp = (list(itertools.permutations(mainword,n_word)))

for i in range(0,6):
  outp[i]=''.join(outp[i])

print(outp)
```

[image]

Comment: I might add that it could be better to use a range up to the len of the list rather than just 6 since the mainword could have more or fewer letters.

Comment: Yes you should use the len() function . I am just give the main logic .it&#39;s up to you to make it generic !
Btw thanks 

Answer (score 7):

You can recombine those tuples with a comprehension like:

#### Code:

```
new_list = [''.join(d) for d in old_list]
```

#### Test Code:

```
data = [
    ('y', 'e', 's'), ('y', 's', 'e'), ('e', 'y', 's'),
    ('e', 's', 'y'), ('s', 'y', 'e'), ('s', 'e', 'y')
]

data_new = [''.join(d) for d in data]
print(data_new)
```

#### Results:

```
['yes', 'yse', 'eys', 'esy', 'sye', 'sey']
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to call [**`str.join()`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) on your string tuples in order to convert it back to a single string. Your code can be simplified with *list comprehension* as:

```
>>> from itertools import permutations
>>> word = 'yes'

>>> [''.join(w) for w in permutations(word)]
['yes', 'yse', 'eys', 'esy', 'sye', 'sey']
```

OR you may also use [**`map()`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) to get the desired result as:

```
>>> list(map(''.join, permutations(word)))
['yes', 'yse', 'eys', 'esy', 'sye', 'sey']
```